# I am trying to fetch data with the Django ORM with filter and exclude both at the same time, but it returns the same data with and without exclude

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to fetch the data from a model with a filter and exclude at the same time. Here is the query

```
sharing = UserSharingPermissions.objects.filter(
    user_id = extra.user_id, is_deleted = False, archived = False
).exclude(pk = extra.current_company.pk)
```

I am trying to exclude the current company from the results but this query includes the current company. I also tried with the Q, but this also gives me the same result.

```
UserSharingPermissions.objects.filter(Q(user_id = extra.user_id, is_deleted = False, archived = False) & ~Q(pk = extra.current_company.pk))
```

I am not sure if am I missing something in a query or something else.

Thanks.

Comment: the problem is that you are referring to a UserSharingPermissions pk. I can imagine you have a relation field on this model for the company... so you have to use a correct lookup, maybe something like this: `company__pk=extra.current_company.pk`

Comment: *The question should be updated to include ... the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: put model code in Question for better answering